# Four different versions of typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to teach myself Angular and while updating my versions (node, angular-cli, ...) I stumbled upon 4 different versions of Typescript. Could anyone tell me the difference?

On the left side of the following screenshot is vscode. The upper part is the result of "ng version". The data cut-off from the screenshot was:

```
 - Angular CLI: 7.3.9
 - Node: 10.15.3
 - OS: win32 x64
 - Angular: 7.1.4
... common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
```

On the right-side a cmd prompt which I opened in my user location.

[image]

I'll try to give my own explanation, please correct me :)

1. `3.1.6` I would say that this is the Typescript version which I am using in my project
2. `3.2.2` Then this might be my global version (the one currently installed in `%AppData%\Roaming\npm`)
3. `3.4.5`... no idea about this one. I just looked it up and it is actually the newest available version at the moment of this post. This is higher than what Angular 7.1.4 supports (3.3 is supported by Angular 8.0.0-beta.9 as I found out [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#800-beta9-2019-03-20)... it's a breaking change so this shouldn't work at all as far as I understand). I wonder if this is number is not displaying something else than Typescript (but what?)
4. `3.2.4` this one puzzles me, I have no clue where it is coming from

I also ran npm list typescript locally and globally. Not sure what this means (as I said, I'm still trying to learn...) but this is the result:

[image]

Comment: which screenshot is from your angular project?

Comment: the one on the left (that's visual studio code, opened in my project location)

Comment: the one printed by `ng version` is all that matters. This is the one `ng` will execute to build the project, and this *version* remains unchanged when the *environment* changes. For example; if you build on another machine after running `npm install`. You shouldn't change this version manually, because Angular requires a specific version and it updates it when you run `ng upgrade` for the next release of Angular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Version `3.1.6`**

You are right, this is your local version of Typescript which is specific to your project.

**Version `3.2.2`**

This is the global version of Typescript. That's why it is not changing in both location when you type `tsc --version`

There are some packages that requires specific versions of other libraries to work properly

**Version `3.2.4`**

It is the dependency of `@angular/cli` i.e. when you'll install `@angular/cli`, it will automatically install this version of `typescript` as a dependency to work property.

**Version `3.4.5`**

It is displaying in the right corner of VS code. Vs code comes with its own version of Typescript which it uses internally because  the editor is written in Typescript.

Answer (score 1):

That's a pretty neat analysis and you have almost got it right in your own explanation. As for the missing pieces, check the explanation below:

3.1.6 as you have rightly noted is the one used installed in your project

3.2.2 is the one that you have installed globally.

3.2.4 is the typescript installed by angular-cli.

3.4.5 is the latest version which is supported by your current version of Visual Code. The intellisense provided by Visual Code will use this version.

To the best of my knowledge your Angular project will run on TSC version 3.1.6 since it's referenced locally. (Correct me if I get this wrong)

You need not worry about having breaking changes since version 3.4.5 is meant only for VS Code to provide intelli-sense.